# Does chainlink have a reliable way to verify the size/format of a file behind a hash stored on IPFS?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, ipfs, chainlink

The idea would be to have a distributed way to retrieve the existence, byte size, and file format from a solidity smart contract using a blockchain Oracle like Chainlink:

Example of image stored on IPFS: `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmYjh5NsDc6LwU3394NbB42WpQbGVsueVSBmod5WACvpte`

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v***/IPFSConsumer.sol";

contract VerifyFile is IPFSConsumer {
    // hashIPFS: QmYjh5NsDc6LwU3394NbB42WpQbGVsueVSBmod5WACvpte
    function verify(bytes32 hashIPFS) public returns (bool, uint256, string) {
         bytes32 requestId = IPFSmetadata(hashIPFS);
         // ... fulfill request with requestId
    }
}
```

or

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v***/IPFSInterface.sol";

contract VerifyFile {
    IPFSInterface internal IPFSmetadata
    
    // hashIPFS: QmYjh5NsDc6LwU3394NbB42WpQbGVsueVSBmod5WACvpte
    function verify(bytes32 hashIPFS) public returns (bool, uint256, string) {
         (bool exists, uint256 size, string format) = IPFSmetadata.fromHash(hashIPFS);
         return ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:
With Chainlink, if you can write a program that can do it, you can do it.

---

Longer answer:
This is a proof of concept for an [IPFS chainlink external adapter.](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/ipfs_cl_ea)

What you'd want to do, is connect your contract to a node that has a job that:

1. Calls the IPFS API from your contract
2. Returns the size of the file from the hash.

Yes, this is possible. No, someone hasn't done this before. You'd be the first. [Here is more information on building and using external adapters](https://blog.chain.link/build-and-use-external-adapters/).